# Using biblatex and memoir together

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I am getting to know the `memoir` class, as I understood this should be the most suitable one for a big project. On the other hand, I'm used to work with `biblatex` and I want to keep it this way.

I found the `\chapterstyle{ell}` nice and I would like to use it. However, at the end of the document I added:

```
\backmatter
\printbibliography
```

which typesets the bibliography section *but* it also typesets an empty "corner" which is derived from the chapter style I'm using:

[image]

For reference, this is how a normal chapter looks like:
[image]

How can I make it look nice? For example, typeset the **Bibliography** in the corner? Or any other suggestions? What would be the best practice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That basically has nothing to do with `biblatex`; it is the design for unnumbered chapters in the style you use, see [MemoirChapterStyles](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/latex-samples/MemoirChapStyles/MemoirChapStyles.pdf) (it make use of the same style). I like this design better as the text always stays in the same place which looks best when flipping through a document. But you can easily define your own style by copying the `ell` code from `memoir.cls`